# Meteor modify auth smart package

Tags: javascript, meteor

How do I modify the auth smart package?

For example the dropdown box after registering show the buttons change password and sign out. I want to add an edit account button. How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an edit button, look here:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled

Specifically, the [login_buttons.html](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons.html) file.

**update:** There's a note at the top of the linked file:

> NOTE: You shouldn't use these templates directly. Instead, use the
>   global {{loginButtons}} template.

Thus, you should find these files in your meteor installation (mine is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\packages\accounts-ui\login_buttons.html`) and edit that file.

*Note this will modify the accounts UI for all your meteor apps.* If you do not want your changes to affect your other meteor apps, you will probably have to "fork" your own accounts-ui package.

There is discussion of making the accounts UI more customizable (like overridable templates), but it is not possible with the current version of Meteor. I suggest describing your use case to the meteor developers. The meteor developers [openly welcome feedback](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/meteor-core/-KHgLzb6xHo/discussion):

> Feedback, please! Some specific areas that we're curious about:
>
> - What sort of customization do you want to do to the loginButtons template?
> - What sort of account restrictions are you likely to use? Everyone must have a username? Everyone must have an email?

Comment: do I just copy that into my app and then replace it?

Comment: no go `Uncaught Error: There are multiple templates named '_loginButtons'. Each template needs a unique name. `

Comment: @Harry: You should find and edit the existing file. I updated my answer.

Comment: That's really nasty, though I'll take what I can get. Would that still work after deploying onto meteor's servers?

Comment: @Harry: Don't forget to give feedback to the meteor dev's so a cleaner solution is possible in the future! I think it will still work (assuming deployment copies files from your machine); if you fork your own accounts-ui package it will work, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `loginButtons`, because currently the default helpers object is public for some reason:

```
Handlebars._default_helpers["loginButtons"] = function(options) {
    return "hello this is test";
};
```

The original helper function looks like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper(
  "loginButtons",
  function (options) {
    if (options.hash.align === "right")
      return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template._loginButtons({align: "right"}));
    else
      return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template._loginButtons({align: "left"}));
  });
```

Here you could replace the default `_loginButtons` template with your own.

However this could easily break with a future version of meteor as `Handlebars._default_helpers` is not really intended to be used in that way. But at least you don't have to work with a fork of meteor.

Also you have to make sure that you add your helper after `accounts-ui-unstyled` does. So if you are using this trick inside another package, be sure to declare `accounts-ui-unstyled` as a dependency.